# Hide KML attributes displayed in bubble

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml

I've scoured the internet for information on how to do this.  What I need is to remove some of the KML attribute data that is being displayed in the information bubble when the object is clicked.

For example, one of the values appearing in the information bubble is KML_2, along with a header value.  How can I suppress some of the attributes so they do not display without editing the actual KML file?  I really only need a few of the attributes from the KML to display, not all.

thanks.

Comment: can you give a link to the KML-file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. At least, not while using the native google maps KML Overlay.

The two workarounds I can think of are:

1.- Use jQuery or CSS to hide the KML_2 attribute. This is tricky because inspecting elements inside the google maps sandbox needs a lot of trial and error, plus you never know when google is going to change the dom hierarchy.

2.- Use a library to parse the KML (for example to geoJSON) to treat is as regular javascript variables. This is feasible only if you don't need to represent complex objects such as attachments.

Comment: Hmm... not what I was hoping for but explains why I couldn't find any answers.  The Navigation tree that is displayed from the KML file is the part that I would like to hide.  The description balloon information is fine to display.

I guess alternatively I would have to change the KML file source as another potential work around.